# ?? operator in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

In the "The Swift Programming Language" book (page 599), I came across this code snippet that kind of confused me. It went like this:

```
func buyFavoriteSnack(person:String) throws {
    let snackName = favoriteSnacks[person] ?? "Candy Bar"
    try vend(itemName:snackName)
}
```

Its explanation was:

> The buyFavoriteSnack(_:) function looks up the given person's favorite snack and tries to buy it for them. If they don't have a favorite snack listed, it tries to buy a candy bar. If they...

How can this explanation map to the "??" operator in the code given. When should/can we use this syntax in our own code?

Comment: There is a "The Swift Programming Language" iBook, and you *can* search for "??" in iBooks. The first hit is the "Nil Coalescing Operator" chapter ...

Comment: Yeah, yeah, I missed it. Happens to the best of us.

Comment: It might help to pronounce `??` as "otherwise" when you're reading code.

Answer (score 92, accepted):

It is "nil coalescing operator" (also called "default operator"). `a ?? b` is value of `a` (i.e. `a!`), unless `a` is `nil`, in which case it yields `b`. I.e. if `favouriteSnacks[person]` is missing, return assign `"Candy Bar"` in its stead.

Comment: Yup, Google wasn't helpful with the question marks. Somehow I missed this in my studies. The nil coalescing operator did it for me.

Comment: If the value of `a` is non-nil, the value of `b` is not evaluated. This is known as short-circuit evaluation.

Comment: The big problem with the ?? operator in Swift is that `a` is not unwrapped as a part of it. But `b` has to be a none optional or implicit unwrapped optional variable.

Comment: @MortenHolmgaard: What do you mean? ["The *nil coalescing operator* (`a ?? b`) unwraps an optional `a` if it contains a value, or returns a default value `b` if `a` is `nil`"](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/BasicOperators.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH6-ID72).

Comment: @Amadan Strange - your right it seems, I just testede it in Playground, but I have multiple places in my apps where I have had to handle this case manually not to get optional(somevalue) when formatting a string.

Answer (score 29):

```
let something = a ?? b
```

means

```
let something = a != nil ? a! : b
```

Comment: I like this the best because it reminds me of my C/C++/PHP days!

Answer (score 27):

This:

```
let snackName = favoriteSnacks[person] ?? "Candy Bar"
```

Is equals this:

```
if favoriteSnacks[person] != nil {
    let snackName = favoriteSnacks[person]    
} else {
    let snackName = "Candy Bar"
}
```

Explaining in words, if the `let` statement fail to grab `person` from `favoriteSnacks` it will assigned Candy Bar to the `snackName`

Comment: Seems Candy Bars are everyones favourite :)

Answer (score 5):

The nil-coalescing operator `a ?? b` is a shortcut for `a != nil ? a! : b`

Answer (score 0):

One addition to @Icaro's answer you can declare values without initialize them. In my opinion this is better:

```
func buyFavoriteSnack(person:String) throws {
    // let snackName = favoriteSnacks[person] ?? "Candy Bar"
    let snackName: String

    if let favoriteSnackName = favoriteSnacks[person] {
        snackName = favoriteSnackName
    } else {
        snackName = "Candy Bar"
    }

    try vend(itemName:snackName)
}
```