# What does "??" stand for in the context of: let x = y ?? "Candy bar"

Tags: swift, operators

I'm new to Swift. Could someone please tell me what "??" stands for and what is its function in the context of

```
let snackName = favoriteSnacks[person] ?? "Candy bar"
```

I have included the complete code below:

```
struct Item{
    var price: Int
    var count: Int
}

class VendingMachine {
    var inventory = [
    "Candy bar": Item(price: 12, count: 7),
    "Chips": Item(price: 10, count: 4),
    "Pretzels": Item(price: 7, count: 11)
    ]
    var coinsDeposited = 0
    func dispenseSnack(snack: String){
        print("dispensing \(snack)")
    }

    func vend(itemNamed name: String) throws {
        guard var item = inventory[name] else {
            throw VendingMachineError.InvalidSelection
        }

        guard item.count > 0 else {
            throw VendingMachineError.OutOfStock
        }

        guard item.price <= coinsDeposited else {
            throw VendingMachineError.InsufficientFunds(coinsNeeded: item.price - coinsDeposited)
        }

        coinsDeposited -= item.price
        --item.count
        inventory[name] = item
        dispenseSnack(name)
    }
}

let favoriteSnacks = [
    "Alice": "Chips",
    "Bob": "Licorice",
    "Eve": "Pretzels",
]

func buyFavoriteSnack(person: String, vendingMachine: VendingMachine) throws {
    let snackName = favoriteSnacks[person] ?? "Candy bar"
    try vendingMachine.vend(itemNamed: snackName)
}
```

Comment: it is a default value in case there is no favorite

Comment: See http://nshipster.com/swift-operators/ - and search for "swift operators"; this search 'trick' works for just about any language. By isolating the type of symbol ("operator"), and then using a localized (in page) search..

Comment: it is called nil coalescing operator

Comment: Possible duplicate of [?? operator in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30772063/operator-in-swift)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Its used to checking nil, if your value will be nil, you will assign default value.**

```
let favoriteSnacks = [
    "Alice": "Chips",
    "Bob": "Licorice",
    "Eve": "Pretzels",
]
```

from your code,

> suppose person = "Eve"

```
let snackName = favoriteSnacks["Eve"] ?? "Candy bar"
```

it will first try to find value from dictionary, i.e. `favoriteSnacks["Eve"]` will give you value `"Pretzels"`.

so it will assign value `Pretzels` to `snackName` variable.

> suppose person = "Allen"

```
let snackName = favoriteSnacks["Allen"] ?? "Candy bar"
```

it will first try to find value from dictionary, i.e. `favoriteSnacks["Allen"]` will give you value `nil`.

In this case it will assign defalut value `"Candy bar"` to your variable `snackName`.

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed explanation!! Really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 2):

Let me please assume here based on its meaning in other languages:

```
   let snackName = favoriteSnacks[person] ?? "Candy bar"
```

?? checks if the value of favoriteSnacks[person] is null. If it is NOT then the value of favoriteSnacks[person] will be assigned to snackName. If the value of favoriteSnacks[person] is null then "Candy bar" will be assigned to snackName.

It is used for having a default value in case favoriteSnacks[person] comes null.

Answer (score 2):

Its the [Nil Coalescing Operator](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/BasicOperators.html) basically giving a default for when the value does not exist.

see also [Providing a default value for an Optional in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24099985/providing-a-default-value-for-an-optional-in-swift)

Comment: don't provide link, instead of this thing you can copy paste the text from that link and paste in answer, because there can be change that webpage will be removed.

Answer (score 0):

Ex. if you get only 5 keys and values in dictionary, but some time getting nil key or value, then error will be come for nil value.
So, here solution for that,

```
 var strName = jsonObjectName ?? "Unknown"
 var intAge = jsonObjectAge ?? 25
```

it means, if jsonObjectName is nil then automatically "Unknown" will be set to strName.

Note: default value provided by "?? value"

Answer (score 0):

Simply explained,

```
let value = x ?? y
```

Is similar to writing,

```
let value = x != nil ? x! : y
```

It checks if x contains nil, if it doesn't then it force unwraps it, otherwise returns y in the above case.