# How to pass a dictionary key through a function in Swift to return a value that is an array

Tags: swift, dictionary, option-type

I've been tasked with writing a basic "Thesaurus" app with just a few entries, but I don't know how to write code that can return a result for for when the key passed through my function has a nil value.

Eventually, the idea is to connect a text field input to a text view output so that the user can enter any word to try to get a response. But I can't even dial in my code without connecting it to a user interface.

```
let synonyms = ["swift" : ["abrupt", "expeditious", "hasty", "nimble", "quick", "rapid", "speedy", "sudden", "unexpected"]]

func buttonPressed(key:String)-> Array<Any> {
        return synonyms[key]!
}

buttonPressed(key: "swift")
```

I can't make this run without force unwrapping, but I will eventually want this function to be able to return a string for a nil input that says "I'm sorry- this word is not in the Thesaurus."

I couldn't figure out what my "else" should be if I used "if let" to unwrap; and I couldn't figure out how to return an array in the case that my key has a value in my dictionary, but return a string in the nil case.

Any advice? Thanks!

Comment: Unrelated but your are going to return `Array<String>` rather than `Array<Any>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A dictionary always returns an optional because the key may not exist. Think of your dictionary as [String: [String]?]

You can unwrap it like so with a *nil coalescing operator*. [?? operator in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30772063/operator-in-swift)

```
func buttonPressed(key:String)-> Array<Any> {
       return synonyms[key] ?? ["I'm sorry- this word is not in the Thesaurus."] 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First to logic. Since your dictionary is `[String:[String]]` you need to return array of `String` as *value* for string *key*

```
  `String` ˇ
synonyms[key] // returns synonyms
^ dictonary       ^ `[String]`
```

So you have this idea: You have text field with input, button and text view. First of all you need to register when button is pressed. So create action for event `.touchUpInside`

```
@IBAction func buttonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
}
```

So you can get text of your text field by getting its `text` property. Same you can do for text view.

```
textField.text 
textView.text
```

So now when button is pressed, get input from text field and if key for text field's text exists, change text of text view to value for this key

```
@IBAction func buttonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
    if let synonyms = synonyms[textField.text!] {
        let text = array.joined(separator: ", ")
        textView.text = text
    }
}
```

Have you noticed this line:

```
let text = array.joined(separator: ", ")
```

... you can’t set text of `textView` just as your array, since your array is of type `[String]`, but `text` property accpets single string. So, this "joins" your array to single `String` with separator between each element from array.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps you.
To return an array:

```swift
let synonyms = ["swift" : ["abrupt", "expeditious", "hasty", "nimble", "quick", "rapid", "speedy", "sudden", "unexpected"]]

    func search(key: String)-> [String] {
        //The default value should also be an array with one String element
        return synonyms[key] ?? ["I'm sorry- this word is not in the Thesaurus."] 
    }

    //This is the button action that will call the search(key:) method
    @IBAction buttonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
        let results = search(key: textField.text ?? "") //get the text from the UITextField
    }
```