# What are the strange messages Swift compiler say about Bool("") means?

Tags: swift, compiler-errors, initialization

Come from python and test Swift with empty string as condition of if statement.

1. What's the error messages mean ?
   `if Bool("") {}` gives three compiler messages

   - `error: value of optional type 'Bool?' must be unwrapped to a value of type 'Bool'`
   - `note: coalesce using '??' to provide a default when the optional value contains 'nil'`
   - `note: force-unwrap using '!' to abort execution if the optional value contains 'nil'`
2. What's the use of this behavior?
   `Bool("")` return `nil`
   what's the purpose to design it like this?

Comment: It will return an optional. You need to unwrap it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not actually 3 error messages. It's 1 error message, plus 2 suggested ways to solve it.

The condition in an `if` statement should be a `Bool`, but the expression you have here, `Bool("")` is of type `Bool?`. The compiler sees that this is just a `Bool` wrapped in an optional, so it suggests ways to unwrap the optional, so as to get the type expected by the `if` statement - `Bool`.

The first suggested way is to provide a default value for when `Bool("")` is `nil` using the `??` operator][1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30772063/operator-in-swift), like this:

```
if Bool("") ?? true {}
```

The second way is to force unwrap it, essentially crashing the program if `Bool("")` is `nil`:

```
if Bool("")! {}
```

Though in this case both of these ways of fixing it is quite silly, because `Bool("")` is always nil. But the point is, these are the two ways the compiler will suggest, when you need to unwrap an optional.

Moving on to your second question, why does `Bool.init` return an optional?

Initialisers may return `nil` because they may *fail*, and these initialisers are called [*failable initialisers*](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Initialization.html#ID224). Initialising a `Bool` with a `String` may fail because only the strings "true" and "false" will successfully create `Bool`s. All other strings do not represent `Bool` values.

Comment: Detailed and clear, thank you for bringing me into Swift !!