# Swift custom decodable initializer without CodingKeys

Tags: swift, decodable

Let's say I have the following decodable struct as an example illustrating what I'm trying to do:

```
struct Object: Decodable {
    var id: String
    var name: String
}
```

and this JSON:

```
[
    {
        "id": "a",
        "name": "test"
    },
    {
        "id": "b",
        "name": null
    }
]
```

Notice that the name property can be `null` sometimes. This would mostly work fine like it is since the json keys match the struct property names, so I don't need a `CodingKey` enum, but the `name` property can be null sometimes. However, instead of making `name` optional, I want to substitute a default string, so I need a custom initializer:

```
struct Object: Decodable {
    var id: String
    var name: String

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        ...
        self.name = <value from decoder> ?? "default name"
        ...
    }
}
```

But this requires a `CodingKey` object. I'm using the default keys. Do I need a `CodingKey` enum as well now? Even though all my keys match up? Or is there a way to have a custom `Decodable` initializer using just the keys as they are?

Is there maybe some sort of default container I can use?

```
let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: <defaultContainer???>)
```

I tried using both of these variants, but neither worked:

> let container = try decoder.singleValueContainer()
>
> let container = try decoder.unkeyedContainer()

How can I have a custom `Decodable` intializer **but also** use the default keys?

Comment: Can't you just use the `Object.CodingKeys` the compiler made for you?

Comment: Only if `Codable` is used, not just one of its constituents.

Comment: @Alexander-ReinstateMonica Unless I'm missing something, that doesn't seem to be available. Trying to get `self.CodingKeys` or `Object.CodingKeys` gives "Type has no member 'CodingKeys'"

Comment: @Jessy, you're right. As soon as I conform to Codable, I can use Object.CodingKeys.self, or just CodingKeys.self to create the container. I guess I have to conform to Codable then instead. Any idea why this is? You should create an answer with your information.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The issue is that `CodingKeys` is only automatically generated for you if didn’t fully manually conform to the relevant protocols. (This is very familiar for Objective-C developers, where a property’s backing ivar would not be automatically synthesized if you manually implemented all the relevant accessor methods.)

So, in the following scenarios, the `CodingKeys` is not created automatically for you:

1. You adopt only `Decodable` and implemented your own `init(from:)`;
2. You adopt only `Encodable` and implemented your own `encode(to:)`; or
3. You adopt both `Encodable` and `Decodable` (or just to `Codable`) and implemented your own `init(from:)` and `encode(to:)`.

So your case falls within the first scenario, above.

It has been suggested that you can get around your conundrum by adopting `Codable`, even though you’ve only implemented `init(from:)` and presumably don’t plan on ever using the `Encodable` behavior. In effect, that is relying upon a side effect of a protocol you don’t plan on really using.

It doesn’t really matter too much, and adopting `Codable` works, but it might be considered to be “more correct” to go ahead and define your `CodingKeys`, rather than relying on the unimplemented `Encodable` side-effect:

```
struct Object: Decodable {
    var id: String
    var name: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id, name
    }

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)

        id = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .id)
        name = (try? container.decode(String.self, forKey: .name)) ?? "Default Value"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The auto-generation for `CodingKeys` is really weird. The scope and availability of it changes based on what members you have.

Say you just have a `Decodable`. These compile:

```swift
struct Decodable: Swift.Decodable {
  static var codingKeysType: CodingKeys.Type { CodingKeys.self }
}
```

```swift
struct Decodable: Swift.Decodable {
  static func `init`(from decoder: Decoder) throws -> Self {
    _ = CodingKeys.self
    return self.init()
  }
}
```

…and you can put them together, if you add `private`.

```swift
struct Decodable: Swift.Decodable {
  private static var codingKeysType: CodingKeys.Type { CodingKeys.self }

  static func `init`(from decoder: Decoder) throws -> Self {
    _ = CodingKeys.self
    return self.init()
  }
}
```

…But make that `func` an initializer, and again, no compilation.

```swift
struct Decodable: Swift.Decodable {
  private static var codingKeysType: CodingKeys.Type { CodingKeys.self }

  init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
    _ = CodingKeys.self
  }
}
```

You can change it to be fully `Codable`, not just `Decodable`…

```swift
struct Decodable: Codable {
  private static var codingKeysType: CodingKeys.Type { CodingKeys.self }

  init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
    _ = CodingKeys.self
  }
}
```

But then you can't use `CodingKeys` at type scope, so the property won't compile.

Considering you probably don't need such a property, just use `Codable`, file a bug with Apple referencing this answer, and hopefully we can all switch to `Decodable` when they fix it.

Comment: `func \`init\`` i didn't even know that was possilbe

Answer (score 2):

You can emulate the behavior using property wrappers but it's not the perfect solution and it's a bit hacky. The problem has been discussed on Swift forums multiple times already.

With a property wrapper:

```
struct Object: Decodable {
    var id: String
    @DecodableDefault var name: String
}
```

Code for the property wrapper:

```
public protocol DecodableDefaultValue: Decodable {
    static var defaultDecodableValue: Self { get }
}

@propertyWrapper
public struct DecodableDefault<T: Decodable>: Decodable {
    public var wrappedValue: T

    public init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.singleValueContainer()
        wrappedValue = try container.decode(T.self)
    }

    public init(wrappedValue: T) {
        self.wrappedValue = wrappedValue
    }
}

extension DecodableDefault: Encodable where T: Encodable {
    public func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.singleValueContainer()
        try container.encode(wrappedValue)
    }
}

extension DecodableDefault: Equatable where T: Equatable { }
extension DecodableDefault: Hashable where T: Hashable { }

public extension KeyedDecodingContainer {
    func decode<T: DecodableDefaultValue>(_: DecodableDefault<T>.Type, forKey key: Key) throws -> DecodableDefault<T> {
        guard let value = try decodeIfPresent(DecodableDefault<T>.self, forKey: key) else {
            return DecodableDefault(wrappedValue: T.defaultDecodableValue)
        }

        return value
    }
}

extension Array: DecodableDefaultValue where Element: Decodable {
    public static var defaultDecodableValue: [Element] {
        return []
    }
}

extension Dictionary: DecodableDefaultValue where Key: Decodable, Value: Decodable {
    public static var defaultDecodableValue: [Key: Value] {
        return [:]
    }
}

extension String: DecodableDefaultValue {
    public static let defaultDecodableValue: String = ""
}

extension Int: DecodableDefaultValue {
    public static let defaultDecodableValue: Int = 0
}
```

To list a few problems:

- you cannot select the default value (can be done differently but it's more complicated)
- if you want to use `let`, you need a separate immutable wrapper.

Answer (score 0):

As a comment made on your question says the compiler generates a `CodingKeys` object for you. You can implement a custom `enum` when the keys mismatch names on your enum or class respecting the JSON data you're receiving from the source.

You can implement your object this way:

```
struct TestObject: Codable {
    var id: String
    var name: String

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)

        let id = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .id)
        let nameOrNil = try? container.decode(String.self, forKey: .name)

        self.id = id
        self.name = nameOrNil ?? "Default value"
    }
}
```

The `container`'s `decode(_:forKey:)` method can throw and error but if you make the implementation to discharge the error and instead returning an optional value with `try?` you can apply a nil coalescing operator to assign your default value whenever the name is not included on the JSON.

Proof here:

```
let json = """
[
    {
        "id": "a",
        "name": "test"
    },
    {
        "id": "b",
        "name": null
    }
]
""".data(using: .utf8)!
let decodedArray = try JSONDecoder().decode([TestObject].self, from: json)
print(decodedArray)
```

References:

- https://medium.com/swiftly-swift/swift-4-decodable-beyond-the-basics-990cc48b7375
- [?? operator in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30772063/operator-in-swift)
- https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/decodable